# Vim script: how to retrieve the timezone offset?

Tags: vim, timezone, strftime

I would like to get the timezone offset of the user environment in a Vim script and that must be portable (Unix/linux/MacOSX, Windows).

For example, if the user is in Paris in summer, its timezone offset is currently +2 (UTC+2).

Portability concerns exclude using external programs or non native scripting engines (Perl, Python, Ruby...).

Answer (score 0):

`:echo strftime("%z")` is as portable as the `%z` format specifier is.

Comment: That is the reason why I'm asking the question:
  1. '%z' is not portable at all
  2. on Windows '%z' gives a timezone name, not an offset

Comment: @dolmen: If OS doesn't supply the information using the standard functions, the VIM is built upon, then you are likely out of luck. VIM isn't programming environment, it is a text editor.